# Select a Child Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

My experience with javascript and jquery is almost null, so...

I'm trying to rotate a object (div_sheet_item), and store its actual rotation inside a hidden input called "rotation".

I can't get the value of the input to calculate the angle, and I don't have idea why.

Here's the code:

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.div_sheet_item_rotate').click(function() {
    var rotation = $(this).parent().find('rotation').val();
    rotation += 90;
    $(this).parent().rotate(rotation);
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<li class="div_sheet_item" style="width: 330px; height: 230px;">
  <div class="div_sheet_item_rotate"><img src="img/ico_rotate.png"/></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="rotation" value="0" />
</li>

<li class="div_sheet_item" style="width: 330px; height: 230px;">
  <div class="div_sheet_item_rotate"><img src="img/ico_rotate.png"/></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="rotation" value="0" />
</li>

<li class="div_sheet_item" style="width: 330px; height: 230px;">
  <div class="div_sheet_item_rotate"><img src="img/ico_rotate.png"/></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="rotation" value="0" />
</li>
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You don't have a tag named rotation `('rotation')`, you should use `('[name="rotation"]')` to get the input

Comment: Don't use hidden inputs for this, use `.data()` to associate values with elements.

Comment: So something like `$(this).parent().data('rotation')`

Comment: Thanks! ('[name="rotation"]') worked fine for me.

Comment: About ".data()" I'll take a look how to use it in my project. Thanks

Comment: @MarcosFelipe. I also recommend you to read a bit about [`CSS Selectors`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). Believe, you will gain time by understanding `$.data()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery .find() function](https://api.jquery.com/find/) takes selector as an argument.
To find an input by name, you should use [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
parent().find('[name="rotation"]')
```

But better way is to assign a class to your rotation input, and then select it by class:

```
<input type="hidden" name="rotation" class="rotation" value="0" />

parent().find('.rotation')
```